# Listener for batch volley request

Tags: android-volley

I am running volley requests in a loop to get avatars for my contacts.
I am using singleton method to create requests and add it to my requestQueue.

```
for (int i=0 ; i< contactList.length; i++) {
    GsonRequest request = new GsonRequest(contactList[i].name)
    volleyHelper.addToRequestQueue(request);
}
```

is there a way for me to know when all of the volley requests are completed ?

I have tried adding a tag to my volley request as well.

```
 request.setTag("groupTag");
```

Comment: I have the same question. Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: No. the only solution i was able to come up with was having a count (integer) to be incremented for every onResponse and onError and keep checking against the contactlist length.

Comment: Same here. I used a count as well.

Comment: Anyone find a solution to this?